# Partially hiding fixed footer on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My fixed footer has an arrow icon on top of it. Clicking the arrow should "lower" the footer below the page until only the arrow is visible. Clicking it again should bring back the footer.

I tried playing with the bottom value but it doesn't hide the footer, only pushes it below while the page becomes taller to make room for it:

```
$('#footer_arrow').toggle(function() {
    $('#footer_wrap').css('bottom', '-84px');
}, function() {
    $('#footer_wrap').css('bottom', '0');
});
```

I want the same but with the footer actually disappearing below the page with just the arrow visible on top of it.

[image]

MARKUP:

```
<div id='footer_wrap'>          
    <footer>    
        <div id='footer_arrow'></div>
        <div>       
            content
        </div>      
    </footer>   
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#footer_wrap {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 84px;
}
footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 9999;    
    position: relative; 
}
#footer_arrow {
    position: absolute;
    width: 61px;
    height: 23px;
    top: -23px;
    left: 50%;
    background: url(images/footer_arrow.jpg) 0 0 no-repeat;
    z-index: 9999;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: can you post a http://jsfiddle.net with your problem?

Comment: I assume you want the footer to always be "sticky" to the bottom of the page, correct? In which case, positioning should be `fixed`, not `absolute`. `absolute` positions the footer relative to the page, while `fixed` positions it relative to the viewport. After that, the footer should slide off screen properly.

Comment: Wow, position:fixed did the trick. Thanks Brandon!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple things. First off, I recommend using `toggleClass()` instead of `toggle()`. That way, you can just add a class with the required CSS, and toggle it using `toggleClass()`. This way, you can change any styles necessary from pure CSS, instead of making the modifications in the JavaScript code. However, the [`toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/) from jQuery's event handling suite that you are currently using will work just fine nonetheless.

Secondly, to move the footer off screen, you'll need to use `fixed` positioning instead of `absolute` on `#footer_wrap`. Otherwise, the bottom is moving relative to the page, which means it just extends it. However, with `fixed`, the element is positioned at a fixed point in the viewport, which can be moved off screen without extending the page.

```js
$('#footer_arrow').click(function() {
    $('#footer_wrap').toggleClass('down');
});
```

```css
#footer_wrap {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 84px;
}
footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 9999;    
    position: relative; 
}
#footer_arrow {
    position: absolute;
    width: 61px;
    height: 23px;
    top: -23px;
    left: 50%;
    background: url(http://www.placehold.it/61x23) 0 0 no-repeat;
    z-index: 9999;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.down {
    bottom: -84px !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='footer_wrap'>          
    <footer>    
        <div id='footer_arrow'></div>
        <div>       
            content
        </div>      
    </footer>   
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

What You have to do imho is not `.toggle()` a `#footer_arrow` element. You need to `.toggle()` a `#footer_wrap` element after clicking on `#footer_arrow`

Look into this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tdcrsn2j/

I've changed Your HTML & CSS a little, but You can bring it back. It was done just to show case.

Answer (score 0):

go with this

when you want to show

```
$('#footer_wrap').css({"display":"block"});
```

when you want to hide

```
$('#footer_wrap').css({"display":"none"});
```

Comment: Because the `#footer_arrow` is contained within the `#footer_wrap`, it would be hidden as well.